# PowerApps Delete function does not work correctly

Tags: powerapps, power-platform

In my app I am using this code

```
If(Checkbox1.Value; Remove(IdeaBox_1; ThisItem); Notify("Click checkbox to delete"; NotificationType.Error))
```

It checks whethere the Chckbox is ticket. If it is it allows to delete items from Sharepoint list, if it isn't if shows error.

I wanted to change this function so after deletion it will Navigate to another screen but I am unsuccesful.

None of this functions work correctly as they are navigating to next Screen even if Checkbox is unchecked (error message).

```
If(Checkbox1.Value; Remove(IdeaBox_1; ThisItem) && Navigate(Screen10;Fade); Notify("Click checkbox to delete"; NotificationType.Error))
```

```
If(Checkbox1.Value; Remove(IdeaBox_1; ThisItem); Notify("Click checkbox to delete"; NotificationType.Error);Navigate(Screen10;Fade))
```

```
If(Checkbox1.Value; Remove(IdeaBox_1; ThisItem); Navigate(Screen10;Fade)); Notify("Click checkbox to delete"; NotificationType.Error)
```

```
If(Checkbox1.Value; Navigate(Screen10);Remove(IdeaBox_1; ThisItem); Notify("Click checkbox to delete"; NotificationType.Error))
```

```
If(Checkbox1.Value;Remove(IdeaBox_1;LookUp(IdeaBox_1; ID= ThisItem.ID));
Notify("Click checkbox to delete"; NotificationType.Error);Navigate(Screen10;Fade))
```

```
If(Checkbox1.Value; Remove(IdeaBox_1; ThisItem); Notify("Click checkbox to delete"; NotificationType.Error); Navigate (Screen10))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the chaining operator to navigate after the removal, which in your language will be `;;`:

```
If(
    Checkbox1.Value;
    Remove(IdeaBox_1; ThisItem);; Navigate(Screen10; Fade);
    Notify("Click checkbox to delete"; NotificationType.Error))
```

You can check out the [list of operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/powerapps/maker/canvas-apps/functions/operators), and the page that talks about [how they can change depending on the language](https://learn.microsoft.com/powerapps/maker/canvas-apps/global-apps#authoring-environment).

Answer (score 0):

Checkbox has property called **OnCheck** and **OnUncheck** . Try using that.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/maker/canvas-apps/controls/control-check-box